# Insert mysql data from android app

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am trying to insert data to mysql database from my android app. I have php file code like this:

```
<?php

// Connection data
    $host = 'xxxx';;
    $uname = 'xxx';
    $pwd = 'xxx';
    $db = 'xxxx';


    $con = mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("connection failed");
    mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("db selection failed");

    $nombre=$_REQUEST['nombre'];
    $asunto=$_REQUEST['asunto'];
    $comentario=$_REQUEST['comentario'];

    $flag['code']=0;

    if($r=mysql_query("insert into comentarios (nombre, asunto, comentario) values('$nombre','$asunto','$comentario') ",$con))
    {
        $flag['code']=1;
        echo"hi";
    }

    print(json_encode($flag));
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

And in my android app I am using this code:

```
   class CreateNewComment extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

                /**
                 * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
                 * */
                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyActivity.this);
                    pDialog.setMessage("Enviando comentario..");
                    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    pDialog.show();
                }

                /**
                 * Creating product
                 * */
                protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                    String nombre = inputnombre.getText().toString();
                    String asunto = inputasunto.getText().toString();
                    String comentario = inputcomentario.getText().toString();

                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("nombre", nombre));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("asunto", asunto));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("comentario", comentario));

                    // getting JSON Object
                    // Note that create product url accepts POST method
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                            "POST", params);

                    // check log cat fro response
                    Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

                    // check for success tag
                    try {
                        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                        if (success == 1) {
                            // successfully created product
                            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Comunidad.class);
                            startActivity(i);

                            // closing this screen
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            // failed to create product
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    return null;
                }

                /**
                 * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
                 * **/
                protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                    // dismiss the dialog once done
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                }

            }
        }
```

I always get the error "Invalid IP Address" and in the console I get the error that android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException. Thanks.

Comment: see that answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Don't use deprecated `mysql_*` functions; use PDO / MySQLi instead. Invalid IP address... is your URL valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all dont use `mysql_*` api, its dead old deprecated, use **mysqli** or **PDO**. and for PHP script you are not sending a valid json response to client.

```
header('Content-type: application/json'); //put header
print(json_encode($flag));
mysql_close($con);
```

and for Android use [**AsyncTask**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) keep the main UI thread free.

You can use library like **[Volley](http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/)** to make your life easier. It will make network calls very easy

**Update**

**PHP with PDO**

```
// Connection data
$host = 'xxxx';;
$uname = 'xxx';
$pwd = 'xxx';
$db = 'xxxx';

//Connect to DB using PDO
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db.';charset=utf8', $uname, $pwd);

$nombre     = $_REQUEST['nombre'];
$asunto     = $_REQUEST['asunto'];
$comentario = $_REQUEST['comentario'];

$flag['code']=0;

//Insert into DB
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO comentarios 
                            (nombre, asunto, comentario) 
                     VALUES (:nombre, :asunto, :comentario)");
$stmt->execute(array(
    ':nombre' => $nombre, 
    ':asunto' => $asunto, 
    ':comentario' => $comentario
));

//Check for affected rows
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    $flag['code']=1;
}

header('Content-type: application/json'); //put header for json
print(json_encode($flag));
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, can you help to do this in my example? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your code in `doInBackground(...)` method of an async task in Android. Your network related tasks are not supposed to run on the main thread and `doInBackgroung()` will run your task on a background thread and publish the result on main thread in `onPostExecute(...)` method where you can update your UI.

For more information try this link:
[Make an HTTP request with android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android?answertab=active#tab-top)